# Alternative to Spring-Kafka (Kafka libraries/implementation)

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want suggestions of alternatives to Spring-Kafka.

I have used Kafka integrated in Spring in my application. I want to explore any alternative libraries available. Would be good if comparative analysis is share between libraries.

Comment: pure kafka java clients?

Comment: any libraries on native Kafka. Like Spring does gives flexibility of just integrating kafka and setting properties/configurations to kick start kafka. Are there other libraries on Kafka like Spring?

Comment: May be you're already aware of it but if you don't, take a look at Kafka Streams https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/

Comment: @Fares Thanks, I knew about KafkaStreams but did not consider them an option until reading your comment! They fit my use case actually.

Comment: Spring kafka also supports Kafka Streams

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the plain Java API ... Put `site:github.com + kafka` in your favorite search engine...

- `wix/greyhound` (seems pretty simple, and based on ZIO)
- `zio-kafka` (ZIO is cool)
- `ExpediaGroup/rhapsody` (Worth a look)
- `dropwizard/dropwizard-kafka` (my personal 2nd choice)
- Reactor Kafka (I think Spring-Kafka / Spring Cloud Streams kinda took over this project)
- Akka Alpakka (Akka is a great framework)
- SmallRye Reactive Messaging (with or without Quarkus) (one I would pick for new projects)
- Micronaut Kafka (Good for webapps)
- Vert.x Kafka client (Reactive, functional programming is awesome)

... probably more