# Kafka as a message queue for long running tasks

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am wondering if there is something I am missing about my set up to facilitate long running jobs.

For my purposes it is ok to have `At most once` message delivery, this means it is not required to think about committing offsets (or at least it is ok to commit each message offset upon receiving it).

I have the following in order to achieve the competing consumer pattern:

- A topic
- X consumers in the same group
- P partitions in a topic (where P >= X always)

My problem is that I have messages that can take ~15 minutes (but this may fluctuate by up to 50% lets say) in order to process. In order to avoid consumers having their partition assignments revoked I have increased the value of `max.poll.interval.ms` to reflect this.
However this comes with some negative consequences:

- if some message exceeds this length of time then in a worst case scenario a the consumer processing this message will have to wait up to the value of `max.poll.interval.ms` for a rebalance
- if I need to scale and increase the number of consumers based on load then any new consumers might also have to wait the value of `max.poll.interval.ms` for a rebalance to occur in order to process any new messages

As it stands at the moment I see that I can proceed as follows:

- Set `max.poll.interval.ms` to be a small value and accept that every consumer processing every message will time out and go through the process of having assignments revoked and waiting a small amount of time for a rebalance

However I do not like this, and am considering looking at alternative technology for my message queue as I do not see any obvious way around this.
Admittedly I am new to Kafka, and it is just a gut feeling that the above is not desirable.
I have used RabbitMQ in the past for these scenarios, however we need Kafka in our architecture for other purposes at the moment and it would be nice not to have to introduce another technology if Kafka can achieve this.

I appreciate any advise that anybody can offer on this subject.

Comment: the issue I see is the 15 minutes processing time for a message. Can't that message be sliced, paralellized in some way, so kafka distributes the load among your processors/consumers? - Instead of a big message that takes 15 minutes, 1000 small messages (that may also take 15 minutes, but avoiding your poll and repartitioning issue)

Comment: The issue we have is that some of our processing by increasing parallelism massively the end to end process actually slows down due to each message requiring the same pieces of data in order to process each message regardless of the amount of work that is contained in processing each message.
We also have scenarios where we call out to external systems to sync data, and depending on the size of the data being synced then message processing times can vary. Sure, where possible we aim to have very small pieces of work for each message, and high parallelism, but this is not always possible.

Comment: what about decoupling consuming and processing? Something like a bunch of consumer threads that feed to a processor pool. Those consumers are responsible of controlling the timing of Kafka polls, while the others do the hard work. If, for example, you need to sync the data, make responsible of that process a different thread than the kafka consumer, decouple it; This way, even if there's a 30 min upload right there on another thread, your consumers keep buffering the messages and/or feeding another processors.

Comment: @GerardMurphy Were you able to solve this issue? If so, can you tell how you handled it?

Comment: The way to solve this issue is to decouple the consumer poll from the thread processing the message and to manually commit offsets.
When the thread has completed processing of the message, the offset can then be committed. When this is done the consumer must re-seek back to the next message after the last committed offset.
I implemented this several years ago for a client but I do not have access to that code.
I am currently looking for a library that supports this in the hopes of not having to write it again. Please share if you find one.

Comment: https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference/ looks promising, I tried it out and it message processing happens on a separate thread to consumer poll.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56185568/alternative-to-spring-kafka-kafka-libraries-implementation for some other possible libraries to try.

Comment: @Nobita see the answer to this question. We took the suggestion posted by Donal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way we got around the issues we were having was as suggested in the comments.
We decided to decouple the message processing from the consumer polling.

On each worker/consumer there were 2 threads, one for doing the actual processing and the other for phoning home to Kafka periodically.

We also did some work with trying to reduce the processing times for messages.
However some messages still take time that can be measured in minutes.
This has worked for us now for some time with no issues.

Thanks for this suggestions in comments @Donal

Comment: So basically after receiving a message, you are sending it to a thread pool for processing and then doing a manual commit. Am i right?

Comment: Well in our case, we do not have a thread pool, and we also only commit the message after it has been processed. We run our workloads in Kubernetes and scale up/down the consumers as needed. Each consumer container has 2 threads. We offload the processing to a different thread, and then on the main thread we poll kafka at a specific interval. This in effect tells kafka that the consumer is still responding so that the consumer does not get kicked out of the consumer group and its partition assigned to a different consumer.

Comment: I am just finishing a big data solution ingestion using reactor-kafka. (Kafka by Azure Event Hubs)
Previously, I implemented the solution as you did here. This time I had to find a solution already developed. reactor-kafka manages the poll on a separate thread and it implements backpressure where it only pushes messages to consumers when there is demand. This is beautiful to observe working. This does require using Project Reactor, but the benefits I've seen have made it worthwhile. Overall there is a lot less code. No futures, no executors yet massively scalable through reactor Schedulers.

Comment: How are you doing the poll to prevent timeout? I'm using Kafka-Flow for .NET and when I create a thread for processing, I'm still seeing the consumer kicked out of the consumer group.

Answer (score 7):

Using Kafka as a Job queue for scheduling long running process is not a good idea as Kafka is not a queue in the strictest sense and semantics for failure handling and retries are limited. Though you might be able to achieve a compromise by playing around with certain configuration for rebalance or timeout, it is likely to remain brittle design. Simple answer is that Kafka was not designed for these kind of usecases.

The idea of `max.poll.interval.ms` is to prevent livelock situation ([see](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread)), but in your case, consumer will send a false positive to the Kafka broker and will trigger a rebalance as there is no way to distinguish between a livelock and a legitimate long process.

You should think about the tradeoffs between living with the negative consequences you mentioned Vs. introducing a new technology which helps you to model a job queue in a better way. For a more complex usecase, check out [how slack is doing it](https://slack.engineering/scaling-slacks-job-queue-687222e9d100).

Comment: I don't see why using Kafka is a bad idea as it supports immutable message topics with a configurable retention period, making it a robust option for a job queue. 
Consumer groups provide a great way to do parallel message processing, that is easy to scale, with the invariant that a message will only be processed by one consumer in the same consumer group at a time, if configured correctly.
The issue with messages that take a long time to process, is that it adds complexity to the management of the consumer poll which must be decoupled from message processing.

Comment: If Kafka is already is in your tech stack, it is OK. Otherwise it is just another case of _golden hammer antipattern_ where a technology which is not designed as a queue and need 3 runtime instances (for a prod ready setup) are introduced just inorder to implement a job scheduler